# JQuery: Autocomplete form submitting

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, form-submit, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the jQuery Autocomplete function to submit a form when an item has been selected or an enter has been pressed upon selection. using PHP, Javascript and HTML.

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong as I am not that experienced in javascript or jQuery. I've searched this site and others for solutions and they all do not seem to work on my code. I'm probably doing something wrong and can't seem to figure out what.

This is the script

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableproducts = [ <?php echo $tag_list; ?> ];
        $( "#products" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableproducts,
            select: function(event, ui) { 
                $("#products").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#partno_item_form").submit(); }
        });

    });

</script>
```

This is the form and the input field related to #products

```
echo '<form method="POST" name="partno_item_form">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="products" name="item_select" class="autocomp">
            </td>
      </form>
```

Your assistance in troubleshooting this issue is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like, in your `select:` option, you're submitting the form. Is the `select` option fired when someone selects an option from your auto-complete list?

Comment: I do not know for sure. I'm not even exactly sure what you mean. I think jQuery detects that part. 

I'm still trying to figure out the javascript syntax and how it handles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector:

```
$("#partno_item_form")
```

[selects elements by **id**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Your form does not have an `id` of `partno_item_form`, so `submit()` is never being called for it.

Change your selector in the `select` event handler to:

```
$("form[name='partno_item_form']").submit();
```

Using the [attribute equals value selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) will allow you to select the form by its `name` attribute.